# execute lame with NSTask but No Output

Tags: objective-c, nstask, lame

I'm new to `Objective-C`.  Currently I'm trying to execute lame with `NSTask`.  The following code seems to be working because `Xcode's` output space shows me lame's standardoutput i.e. shows same as lame's output on Terminal.

But I can't get any output file i.e. test.mp3 on my desktop.  Why I can't get any output?  Is there any wrong with my code?

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/local/bin/lame"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Users/xanadu62/Music/test.wav",nil]];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/Users/xanadu62/Desktop/test.mp3"]];
[task launch];
```

Also, I'd like to use "--preset extreme" as lame option.  But "task `setArguments`:" doesn't allow to use this option as argument.  I'd like to know how can I solve this issue too.

Comment: You are not passing shell paths to NSTask.  Actually, sorry...  I guess that'll be okay since no name contains space.  Meanwhile, doesn't lame take some settings to configure?  And you have no NSPipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/local/bin/lame"];

[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    @"--preset",
                                    @"extreme",
                                    @"/Users/xanadu62/Music/test.wav",
                                    @"/Users/xanadu62/Desktop/test.mp3", 
                                    nil]
];

[task launch];
```

You don't need to use pipes.

```
usage: lame [options] <infile> [outfile]

    <infile> and/or <outfile> can be "-", which means stdin/stdout.
```

Comment: Nice, txs for the feedback!

Comment: BTW: http://boredzo.org/make-ram-disk/ shows NSTask & Co. in Action (Source Code at bottom of page).

Answer (score 1):

Never used lame, but by looking at the docs the correct terminal command would be

"lame --preset extreme /Users/lawrencepires/Desktop/test.mp3  /Users/lawrencepires/Desktop/test1.mp3"

test.mp3 being the input file, test1.mp3 being the output file.

Working Code - (may be worth changing for live output)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
// Insert code here to initialize your application


[self lameconvert];
}


- (void)lameconvert {

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/local/bin/lame"];
NSArray *argArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"--preset",@"extreme",@"/Users/xanadu62/Music/test.wav",@"/Users/xanadu62/Music/test.wav",nil];

[task setArguments:argArray];

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
NSLog(@"Conversion Complete");


}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks your answer also solve my question.  But accepted answer is to be one.  So I marked first answer as accepted answer.